# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'app_metadata')

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Why I get this error and how can I fix it ?

```
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'app_metadata')
```

here is my code:

```
export const verifyJWT = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];

    if(!bearerHeader) {
      throw new Error('err');
    }

    const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');

    const token = bearer[1];

    req.user.app_metadata = {
      isAdmin: false,
      isTenantAdmin: false,
      role: 'ADMIN'
    };
    
    next();
  }
```

types:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      user: {
        user_metadata: IUser;
        app_metadata: IUserAppMetaData;
      }
    }
  }
}

declare module '@supabase/supabase-js' {
  interface UserMetadata extends IUser {};
}
 
declare module '@supabase/supabase-js' {
  interface UserAppMetadata extends IUserAppMetaData {};
}

export interface IUserAppMetaData {
  isAdmin: boolean;
  isTenantAdmin: boolean;
  role: PSM_ADMIN_ROLES;
};

export interface IUser extends ISignUpAdmin {
  id: UUID;
  tenantID: UUID;
  isAdmin: boolean;
};

export interface ISignUpAdmin {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  role: Roles;
  city: string;
  street: string;
  zipcode: string;
  company: string;
  category: string;
  domain: string;
  code: number;
};
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong I added my types and got no errors in my files only when I execute the function/middleware.

I hope you can help me to fix the error and say me what did I wrong

thank you!!

Comment: It's telling you that `req.user` is `undefined`. What makes you believe it should be otherwise?